# Hook for editing search results in mediawiki

Tags: hook, mediawiki

Well, I want to edit the search results that the normal search engine of the wiki returns, so when i do a namespace search, only the name of the file appears, and not namespace:file, right now Im using search update hook but i dont think that is the one i need, any ideas?

Ps: im trying to use the normal search (yeah i know it sucks), so no i cant update to sphinx or lucene

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse) and tweak your skin files. It has been done in a couple wikis I use ([Wikiprogress](http://www.wikiprogress.org) and [Wikigender](http://www.wikigender.org)). I have found it much a better searching solution than the one that comes by default with Mediawiki.

Comment: yeah i tried it, the problems are the adds, i dont want the adds on my page